# Redirect to login page if user is not logged in

Tags: php, redirect

I created my website, but I want to require users to log in before they can access certain pages.  For example, my home page is *index.php*, having url (www.sample.com/index.php).  There is a login button in this page will redirect to *login.php*.  In *login.php* page I have an edit button, and `onclick` event takes to *edit.php*.

Now, if I paste the URL www.sample.com/edit.php in the addressbar, it goes directly to *edit.php*, but I want it to take to *index.php* if the user is not logged in, similar to how Google requires authentication.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: I checked for session value

Comment: Use a conditional statement **if** **else**

Comment: @user3386779 do you mind if you show us your code. it is much easier too look your code and help you with it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set a session after login successful and in edit.php check for it, if session is not set, redirect it to homepage.

**login.php :**

```
//put this at the first line
session_start();
//if  authentication successful 
$_SESSION['login'] = true;
```

**edit.php :**

```
if(!$_SESSION['login']){
   header("location:index.php");
   die;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Then please check the session on edit.php...If on edit.php, session is not there, then it wll redirected to index.php..I m talking about the session which will be started when user will login successfully

Answer (score 1):

You can use session variable to do this, you ust be set session on login.

So on edit page starting you can write following code to check wheter user is logged in or not..

```
 session_start();
if(!issset($_SESSION['login_session'])){
    header("Location:login.php");
    exit(); 
}
```

Comment: your condition is bad, a simple `issset($_SESSION)` is not enough. another session might be set somewhere else.